# How do I specify a network subnet

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

When we create a network with a custom subnet we get the error:

`Invalid value for field 'resource.networkInterfaces[0].subnetwork': ''.  Subnetwork was not specified for a custom network`

How do we specify the subnet for the job to use?

Comment: Could you clarify how you are setting this with the SDK?

Comment: We use the "network" option in PipelineOptions, but there is no "subnet" option that I can find.

Comment: ie, this function https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/java-sdk/JavaDoc/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/options/DataflowPipelineWorkerPoolOptions#setNetwork-java.lang.String-

Comment: Updated now that support has been added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Updated): Dataflow now supports subnetworks, using the [--subnetwork](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/runners/google-cloud-dataflow-java/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/runners/dataflow/options/DataflowPipelineWorkerPoolOptions.java#L151) flag.  The expected format is "**regions/REGION/subnetworks/SUBNETWORK**".

Comment: Can you provide a link to where this is mentioned in Google's documentation?

Comment: Keep in mind tho that it should be `regions/REGION/subnetworks/SUBNETWORK` so `regions` not `zones`

Comment: Thank you; I've updated the answer, and asked Compute Engine to update their documentation.

Comment: How do we add subnetwork in yaml file used by deployment manager ? I am getting this error with deployment manager  ```Invalid value for field 'resource.networkInterfaces[0]':\
    \ '{  \\\"network\\\": \\\"https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/user-me/global/networks/defa...'.\
    \ Subnetwork should be specified for custom subnetmode network\",\"statusMessage\"\```